# Some questions about the "USE_CREDENTIALS" permission

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider, credentials, android-syncadapter

i have some questions regarding the ["USE_CREDENTIALS" permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_CREDENTIALS) on android :

1. it seems that it's used for using your own syncadapter . can it also be used for communicating with other syncaAdapters (or their content providers) , which belong to other apps ?
2. if the answer to #1 is no , why does it exist on the first place , if it's your own syncAdapter anyway?
3. does it have any other uses than for syncAdapter?
4. if i don't need any authentication , is it possible to use syncAdapter without this permission?
5. even without using syncAdapter , is it possible to access synced accounts , use their credentials and do special things with them (for example , collecting data that was recently synced) , assuming you have this permission (and/or others) ?